# VB6 show a messagebox saying "finished"

Tags: vb6

code that will show a message box after inserting data on the last cell of a column in datagrid. my program runs like this, when i click a button, a value will be added to the first cell then will triggered rs.MoveNext, when i click again the button the same process takes place, the problem is that when i reach the last cell and click the button again, the data i put on the last cell just replace with the new one. please help me with a code that will stop rs.MoveNext if i reach the end of file.

Comment: `If NOT rs.EOF Then rs.MoveNext End If`

Comment: `MsgBox("Finished")`

Comment: that's not working, it just keeps on changing the value of the last cell. btw i just figured it out, i just create a loop that will show a message box once it reach the value of recordcount

Answer (score 0):

Try  using MsgBox "Finished" without using the brackets ("").